# ul li li remove :before :after in second level.

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want do something like that:
I trying to ul first-child but no result. :(.

```
<ul>   
    <li></li> /* + :before */
    <li></li> /* + :before */
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li> /* remove :before or never create :before */
        </ul>
    </li> /* + :before */
    <li></li> /* + :before */
</ul>
```

please help.

Comment: What does that mean ? Where is the `css` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your CSS. Don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 9):

`:first-child` just gets you the first child. If you want to remove `:before` from nested `li`s, set `content: none` for those `li`s:

```
ul li li:before {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: I saw `content:''` also works, is that right and valid ?

Comment: @Recovering Since 2003: That's valid, but not the right solution - what that does is generate an empty pseudo-element. If it *does not generate* a pseudo-element, then you're seeing a bug in a very old browser. If you want to maximize browser compatibility, you can do `content: ''; content: none;`, but for today's browsers it's not necessary - even IE8 treats each value correctly.

Comment: Ohh. thx I fixed my code. Thx all for help. :)