# Why does my :after override class not work in IE10 & IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a class that I am extending with another class name (that contains more specific changes). For some reason the original rule is not being overwritten in IE9 and IE10, but it works in every other browser including IE8!? The style sheet containing the overriding class (style) is also referenced after the the stylesheet where the original class is located.

The original class is: 
`.panel:after { content: "" , etc...}`

The new class is:
`.panel.sales-tip:after { content: "\E006", etc... }`

**Internet Explorer Web Inspector:**
The web inspector shows the following information. Why does are both classes seemingly disabled but when I unchecked the ".panel:after" the other style then works, and does it thing. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, there is a difference between `content:"";` and `content:none;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106066/ul-li-li-remove-before-after-in-second-level/19106109#comment28249875_19106109

Comment: Are IE 9 and 10 slipping into IE 7 document mode? You can check by opening the Developer Tools. Here’s a screenshot that shows where the document mode is indicated: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CwYVL.png. If the browsers are going into IE 7 mode, the `::before`and `::after` rules wouldn’t work.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, I just double checked and even in both "Document: IE10" & "Document Mode: Standards" and "Document Mode: IE9" & "Document Mode: IE9 Standards", it's doing the same thing. Oddly enough in IE8 Document Mode, and IE8 Standards, everything works as it should.

Comment: @leetou: gotcha. That is odd — I can only imagine that you’ve got some other rule with `::before` or `::after` in it that’s overriding the ones you’ve includes, and that it uses a CSS selector not supported by IE 8 (or is inside a media query — IE 8 doesn’t support those either). Although I assume the developer tools don’t indicate such a rule?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was because I had this rule — `font-size: 0px` — in my `.panel:after` declaration, and it wasn't being overridden by the new `font-size: 2.2em` rule in the `.panel.sales-tip:after` declaration.

I ended using a fixed size of `font-size: 35px` in the `.panel.sales-tip:after` declaration.

I'm glad that fixed the problem, but does anybody know why it wouldn't override? Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, well worked-out. That is odd. I guess it’s an IE 9/10 bug. I’m not quite clear why you need a `font-size:0px` in the first class though.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, Yes, looking back I'm not sure why I did either :S...since that pseudo element was just there to create a CSS triangle.